# Changing every other row in a matrix in R

Tags: r

Would anyone be able to show me a way of changing every second row in a column of a matrix to have the opposite sign to the one it currently has (e.g. changing a 4 to -4, or a -4 to 4)? I can do it with a for loop, but I was hoping there might be a more efficient method for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an *even* number of rows, try

```
c(1,-1)*M
```

Where `M` is your matrix.

Otherwise, use

```
(2*(row(M) %% 2)-1)*M
```

EDIT: Carl Witthoft's suggestion:

```
rep(c(1,-1),length=nrow(M))*M
```

works with any matrix.

Comment: Nice: I think you can simplify to  `rep(c(1,-1),length=nrow(M))*M`

Comment: @zx8754
Ok, I think I marked it as answer. I'm not quite sure though, am new on this site.
Thanks

Comment: @Mike great, voting up and marking as an answer are the best way of thanking the contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer:
`rep(c(1,-1),length=nrow(M))*M`